# Top up account on website

Tags: paypal

I successfully established the paypal pay function on my website. I actually haven't tried it in live, but it's working in the sandbox mode. Is there a way for my user's to top up their account on my website? It's easier for them to transfer money to my website in advance then pay from that amount every time they purchase my service. Of course, I would also like to give them the opportunity to withdraw this amount.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Adaptive Payments (Pay) API or the MassPay API to send money to one account or group of accounts.

Comment: I am afraid you misunderstood me. I don't want to send money to other paypal accounts. I want to transfer money to an account registered on my webpage. So the user transfers $50 to me then $50 appears on their account. If they want they can withdraw this amount to their paypal account from my website.

Comment: The user can either transfer money via logging into their account and sending money through the send money tab, otherwise you would need to use adaptive payments.  You would need to have the users set up permissions on their account to allow your application to process payments ont heir account.